MySQL table partition on non primay key column
Below is my table structure, the primary key id is a combination of reportedUserId_reporteeUserId. I used it to perform INSERT IGNORE queries, I want to implement a table partition on the scanType column, but for that, I have to add it in primary-key, and inserted values will be duplicated because of multiple scanType values, but I want it to be unique.
So is it possible to maintain unique record on id(reportedUserId_reporteeUserId) and table partition on scanType?
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id             | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| reportedUserId | bigint       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| reporteeUserId | bigint       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| createdTime    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| remarks        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| contestId      | bigint       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| scanType       | int          | NO   |     | 1       |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


Not possible.  MySQL has not implemented any uniqueness constraint across partitions.
I suggest that PARTITIONing is probably not of any use.  Please provide the query(s) that you think might benefit so I can discuss further.  Consider using composite index(es) starting with scanType instead of depending on partitioning; the indexing approach is likely to be at least as fast.
